# Two or more functions are not working when they are used in a Check parameter

Tags: inno-setup

I have been trying to make work two functions in a `Check`. When I use more than one function none of them work. For example:

```
[Files]
Source: MyProg.exe; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: portable and install;  
Source: MyProg.dll; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: portable and install;  
Source: MyProg.ini; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: portable and install;
```

When i only use one check portable or install, it works although i know that i can repeat the source Dir and place the other check like this:

```
[Files]
Source: MyProg.exe; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: portable;  
Source: MyProg.dll; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: portable;  
Source: MyProg.ini; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: portable;

Source: MyProg.exe; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: install;  
Source: MyProg.dll; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: install;  
Source: MyProg.ini; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: install;
```

But as I have many files, I want to use more than one function in one `Check` for not to be copying and pasting too many sources lines in the `[Files]` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
[Files]
Source: MyProg.exe; DestDir: {app}; Check: portable and install
```

is **not identical** to:

```
[Files]
Source: MyProg.exe; DestDir: {app}; Check: install  
Source: MyProg.exe; DestDir: {app}; Check: portable
```

The first says *install the file, when both `portable` **and** `install` are true/selected*. What probably never happens.

While the latter says *install the file, when either `portable` **or** `install` are true/selected*.

---

So, you want to use `or` operator instead of `and`:

```
[Files]
Source: MyProg.exe; DestDir: {app}; Check: portable or install
```

Comment: Is it the same when i use Check: IsWin64; or Check: "not IsWin64"; can i combine them? Ex: check: IsWin64 or install; ?

Comment: Yes. Though `IsWin64 or Install` does not make sense to me. You probably want `IsWin64 and Install`.

Comment: Ahh ok, so i can combine them like: Check: Iswin64 and install or portable

Comment: You better write `IsWin64 and (install or portable)` to make it more obvious what you mean.